# Check winner in puzzle

Tags: c#

I want to design a function that checks whether Player A or B wins.
Right now I'm just reusing a bunch of code. I would like to use the same function for each if possible. Right now I have two different if statements, one for A and for B. Any tips on how I should merge them?
Can I create a function which takes in both A and B values and use some kind of tenary function with just one if statement?

```
if (label[x,0].theValue() == A && label[x,1].theValue() == A && label[x,2].theValue) == A)
{
   MessageBox.Show("A Wins!");
}

if (label[x,0].theValue() == B && label[x,1].theValue() == B && label[x,2].theValue) == B)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("B wins!");
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code otherwise nobody can help you. A screen of the app would be also appreciated. Is this a Forms application?

Comment: First thing I would recommend is not to get these values from the UI. But as per @chris579 please post more of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```
public string CheckWinner(int x){
  if( "your code" ) { return "A wins"; }
  if( "your code" ) { return "B wins"; }
}
```

And then on your main function (form)

```
MessageBox.Show(CheckWinner(1));
```

I Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a funktion to check if a given player has won like this (assuming A and B in your code are Player-objects)

```
private bool HasWon(Player player)
{
    if (label[x,0].theValue() == player && label[x,1].theValue() == player && label[x,2].theValue() == player)
    {
        return true;
    }
        return false;
}
```

You can use this function like so:

```
if(HasWon(A))
{
    MessageBox.Show("A Wins!");
}
```

or, if you have a List or something like this of all playing players, do like so:

```
foreach(var player in players)
{
    if(HasWon(player))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(player.Name + " Wins!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a method to check if A is the winner:

```
public bool IsAWinner(string x0value, string x1value, string x2value)
{
    if (x0value == "A" && x1value == "A" && x2value == "A")        
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Call this one from your UI code to check if A is the winner, if it isn't, B is the winner.

The idea is to NOT use windows controls in this method; so that it can be tested (loose coupling from UI).

So from your UI:

```
if (IsAWinner(label[x,0].theValue(), label[x,1].theValue(),label[x,2].theValue))
    MessageBox.Show("A Wins!");
else
    MessageBox.Show("B wins!");
```

Also, don't forget to add some exception handling.

Comment: A/B sound like constants or variable in OP post, not an inline string.

Answer (score -2):

While I've never used C# I would imagine the second If statement is not needed. If A wins, then B loses whereas if B Wins A loses.

If A wins ... else B wins!

Sorry I can't give you a code sample, C# isn't my thing.